# Closed form of recurrence equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am solving warm up problem 1.2 from Concrete Mathematics book. I've got the right answer by induction:

$$
f(0) = 0\\
f(n) = 3f(n-1) + 2,
$$

But I can not figure how to simplify it to the closed form. I've looked in the answers and saw this:
$$
f(n) = 3^n -1
$$

Can anyone clarify to me how to get this closed form solution?

Comment: Others will be able to give you more helpful answers if you give a little context. Is there some particular step you that is giving you trouble? What sorts of related facts do you know already? (In the present vacuum, I'd suggest a standard induction proof.)

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question

Comment: @kernel_mode Good edit! This is the type of question that we like to see here! :)

Comment: You might want to read the last two paragraphs of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/315213/43351) to see what lab did below.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, thanks, this clarifies a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $f(m)=g(m)-1$

$\implies g(0)=1$ and $g(m+1)=3g(m)$

$\implies g(m+1)=3^{r+1}g(m-r)$ for $0\le r\le m$

$g(m+1)=\cdots=3^{m+1}\cdot g(0)$